# When i run gulp in node i get this error in ubuntu 18.4 lts

Tags: php, node.js, laravel-5, gulp, ubuntu-18.04

I attached my issue snap.

I install node and npm I also attached that snap.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Without code its difficult to guide you..

Comment: Please include messages/code as text rather than images.

Comment: Search for your error: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgulp%5D+task+function+must+be+specified  Many answers there.

Answer (score 0):

This may be issue due to change introduced in Gulp 4.

If you are using Gulp 4 then check out this [link to Github issue](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2221)